# AngularJS : Functions in Service doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, service

So I'm making a service in angular but when I call it in my controller it doesn't work...
Here is the service :

```
app.service('AllPosts', function(){
    this.posts = [
        {"id":"0","username":"Simon", "age":"18"},
        {"id":"1","username":"Chris", "age":"53"}
    ];
    this.getPosts = function(){
        return this.posts;
    };
    this.getPost = function(id){
        var post={};
        angular.forEach(this.posts, function(value) {
            if(value.id == id){
                post=value;
            }
        });
        return post;
    };
});
```

And in my controller I try to call it like that:

```
app.controller('PostsCtrl', function($scope, AllPosts){
    $scope.posts = AllPosts.getPosts;
});
```

When I try to use the function .getPosts I have an empty white page but if I replace .getPosts by .posts I have my page loading right...

```
$scope.posts = AllPosts.posts;
```

What am I doing wrong guys, please?

Comment: You need to call the function `$scope.posts = AllPosts.getPosts();`. Pro-tip: open your developer tools (hit F12 on Windows or Opt+Cmd+I on Mac). It will help a lot when you get into trouble.

Comment: What about `AllPosts.getPosts()`?

Comment: Thanks for the pro tip, I did it, but it doesn't said nothing wrong...

Comment: The same with the other function, I don't have anything... I also try to put a console.log but nothing appears in my console

Comment: @SimonValèreTrichereau Did you try calling the function? Notice the parentheses on the end. Change `$scope.posts = AllPosts.getPosts;` into `$scope.posts = AllPosts.getPosts();`

Comment: Yeah sorry, I hit enter a bit too quickly, thanks for your answer, I feel bad... I'm a really big noob >_< That was the perfect thing!

Comment: @SimonValèreTrichereau Haha no worries. Good luck!

Comment: @MikeC Thanks for your help :) I'm beginning with AngularJS ... I think that will be fun -_- Ah ah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are assigning `$scope.posts` to a function:

```
$scope.posts = AllPosts.getPosts;
```

You should call the function so that the result of the method call is assigned to `$scope.posts`:

```
$scope.posts = AllPosts.getPosts();
```

Now, `$scope.posts` will be assigned to the posts that are returned by the method.

Answer (score -1):

I edited the code to work as a function or as a variable.

```
app.service('AllPosts', function(){
    var posts = [
        {"id":"0","username":"Simon", "age":"18"},
        {"id":"1","username":"Chris", "age":"53"}
    ];
    this.getPosts = function(){
        return this.posts;
    };
    // or you can do this by calling it.
    this.getPosts = this.posts;
    // Using functional programming and arrow function.
    this.getPost = function(id){
         return this.posts.filter((value) => {
           return value.id == id;
       });
    };
});
```

**In your controller:**
as @Amin Meyghani and @ Mike C mentioned:

```
app.controller('PostsCtrl', function($scope, AllPosts){
    // You need to comment one of these
    // to use it as a function.
    $scope.posts = AllPosts.getPosts();
    // or if you want to use it as avarible .
    $scope.posts = AllPosts.getPosts
});
```